# Why doesn't creating/writing to file with fstream work on windows start up?

Tags: c++, windows, startup, fstream

So here I got this little program which everyone obviously understands.

```
include <iostream>  
include <fstream>  
using namespace std;  

int main () {  

 ofstream myfile;  
  myfile.open ("example.txt");  
  myfile << "Writing this to a file.\n";  
  myfile.close();  
  return 0;  
}
```

This program works just fine, however, the problem is that if I have added it to run on windows start up(in registries `SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run`), the programs starts fine, but it does not create example.txt file. Why is that and how do I avoid it?

Comment: Is it possible that it is creating the file but your working directory is different? Try writing the file to "C:\\example.txt" instead to test.

Comment: Joe might be right. Try looking in C:\Documents and Settings\<user>

Comment: The root C: may be protected. Look at C:\\Temp\example.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It tries to create the file in the current working directory for the process, since you specified a relative path.

Because there is no way to specify the working directory in the `Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` registry setting, the working directory is inherited from the parent process.  The parent process is the shell, explorer.exe which has a working directory of `C:\Windows\system32`.  Since (assuming UAC is enabled) your user doesn't have rights to that folder, no file is created.

Comment: @Newbie I see your deleted answer where you wrote "Thank you! Specifying directory worked". That should have been a comment and so a moderator deleted it. Anyway, if this answers your question you should check the tick next to the answer to mark it as such. Thanks.