# Executable started from registry can't read or write files

Tags: c++, windows, registry, startup

I need to run my executable at windows start, i used the code from the answer to:

[Save Me Simple Add to Startup via Registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15935564/save-me-simple-add-to-startup-via-registry/15937683)

It works. my program gets executed via registry at start up; But the program can't read or write files, it can't even load the icons. Any ideas on how to solve this. (Executing the application normally, has no problems with reading nor writing file; The problem only happens when executed at startup from the registry)

Comment: What methods or means are you using to read and write files?

Comment: The linked answer shows the app registered under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, so it should not be a permissions issue. The app would load under the same user account either way.  If I had to guess (and please, don't make people guess - always show what you are actually doing!), maybe the app is using relative paths to access the files, and the process's current working directory is different depending on whether the app is started via Registry or not. When started by Registry, the CWD is probably not what the app is expecting, so it fails to find/create the files in the right location.

Comment: Is your problem the same as this? [Why doesn't creating/writing to file with fstream work on windows start up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477573/why-doesnt-creating-writing-to-file-with-fstream-work-on-windows-start-up?rq=1)

Comment: @BoPersson: yes, that is the same issue I just described in my comment above, but that discussion goes into more detail about what is actually happening with the CWD.